# Store Animation In Class or Main? Preload All Spritesheets? Optimizing cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Hey hopefully a simple question, roughly "How to optimize?".  I have a game with exactly 5 characters on the screen, randomly selected from a bank of about 50.  They are relatively high resolution (about 300 wide, 600 tall), so each one requires its own 1024x1024 sprite sheet (or possibly 4 together on a 2048x2048).

The big questions are...

1) Should I preload ALL 50 sprite sheets, or cache them as I need them as the player goes through levels?

2) Should each character build its own set of animations inside the character class itself, or should ALL animations be stored in the main HelloWorld?

3) Should I put 4 sprites on a 2048x2048 sprite sheet (when I may only need 1 of the four in a particular level) vs having individual 1024x1024 sheets?

as a sub-note for game flow, a level takes about 1 minute, and it's possible to have multiple of the same character, though just based on odds, it's typically 5 different characters.

Thanks!

Comment: A single image per sprite sheet makes no sense, cram as many as you can into a single sprite sheet (texture atlas). Note that 2048x2048 = 16 MB of memory usage (uncompressed, 32-bit color) so you definitely can't fit them all into memory at the same time. You will definitely want to use .pvr.ccz format (compressed but lossless PVR) and if possible reduce color depth to 16-bit to conserve quite a bit of memory and significantly increase load times.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : I am convinced you meant 'improve' load time ... which it does significantly on most devices.

Comment: schmimprove, schmincrease ... who can tell the difference? :)

Comment: schmeone someone who does JIT texture loading :)

Comment: Not a single image, sorry, a single character...  not sure why anyone would make a sprite sheet for a single image.  Characters are approximately 12 frames each at 250x500 resolution, fully occupying a 1024x1024 square for each character.  So say I have 4 sprites, but on level 2 I only need 1 of the sprites.  Having a 2048x2048 sprite sheet with 3 characters I don't need means loading assets I won't use.  Having four 1024x1024 sprite sheets means I don't have to load as much, but it also means 4 sprite sheets instead of 1.  The bigger concern is where the animations should be stored.